# Is it a theorem of ZF that every partial order can be extended to another that makes the set directed?

Tags: logic, set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

The Order Extension Principle (OEP) is the proposition that every partial order on a set can be extended to a linear order on the same set.  The OEP is a theorem of ZFC but not of ZF, and it is among the many choice principles that appear in a book such as *Axiom of Choice* by Herrlich.

Among notions between those of posets and linearly ordered sets is that of directed sets.  One can think of an analogue of the OEP but for directed sets: every partial order on a set can be extended to an order that makes the set directed.  Is this a theorem of ZF?  (The statement was not on the said book.)

Comment: I see Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms has something to do with axiom of choice, but how it is different from axiom of choice?

Comment: Just a remark for someone who is trying to solve this: any counterexample must have no maximal elements. So "the obvious" attempts with amorphous sets are doomed to fail.

Comment: @CharlieChang See the first paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

Comment: I think I have a proof that this is not provable in ZF but the details are kind of messy and it will take me a little while to write up.

Comment: Actually, the proof I had in mind doesn't seem to work (as I discovered when I tried to actually write it down).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is a model of ZF with a partial order that cannot be extended to a directed order.

Since we're just trying to find a weird object, we can use a Fraenkel-Mostowski permutation model and apply an embedding theorem, such as the First Embedding Theorem in Jech, *The Axiom of Choice*, Chapter 6. (I haven't checked Herrlich's book to see if there is a relevant theorem there.)

Take the set of atoms $A$ to be the free Boolean algebra on a countable set of generators.  For each finite subalgebra $B$ define $G_B$ to be the automorphisms of $A$ fixing $B.$ The permutation group consists of all automorphisms of $A,$ and the normal filter is generated by $\{G_B:\text{finite subalgebras }B\subset A\}.$

This gives us a permutation model $\mathcal N$ which contains the Boolean algebra $A.$ The Boolean algebra gives $A$ the partial order where $a\leq b$ means $a\Rightarrow b.$
Consider a partial order $\preceq$ on $A\setminus\{0_A\}$ extending $\leq.$
I will show that $\preceq$ is not downwards directed i.e. the opposite order is not directed. (I'm dualizing here because it will be notationally neater to use small elements rather than big elements.)

There is a finite subalgebra $B\subset A$ such that $\preceq$ is fixed by the extension of $G_B$ to an automorphism of $\mathcal N.$
Let $a_1,\dots,a_k$ be the atoms of $B$ (the $\leq$-minimal elements of $B\setminus \{0_A\}$).

$A$ is homogeneous, in fact a Fraïssé limit, which means we can pick new elements with any desired consistent relation to a finite set of existing elements, and to extend automorphisms of any finite subalgebra to the whole of $A.$

**Lemma:** For all $i$ and all $0\leq b,c\leq a_i$ we have $b\preceq c \implies b\leq c$.

*Proof:* We only need to consider the case that $b$ and $c$ are $\leq$-incomparable but $b\prec c.$
Let $d=b\wedge c.$
If $d=0$ then we can use an automorphism swapping $b$ and $c$ to deduce $c\prec b.$
If $d>0,$ write $b'=b-d$ and $c'=c-d.$ We can use an automorphism cycling $b'\to d\to c'\to b'$ two times to get from $b'\vee d\prec c'\vee d$ to $d\vee c'\prec b'\vee c'$ and then to $c'\vee b'\prec d\vee b'.$ This gives $c\preceq b.$
In either case we have contradicted antisymmetry of $\preceq.$ $\Box$

Pick $b_1,\dots,b_k$ with $0<b_i<a_i$ and pick $i$ such that $b_i$ is a $\preceq$-minimal element of $b_1,\dots,b_k.$
Suppose for contradiction that there exists $c$ with $c\preceq b_i$ and $c\preceq a_i-b_i.$ We can assume $c<a_j$ for some $j.$ (There is a $j$ such that $c\wedge a_j>0$; pick $c'$ to be any $0<c'<c\wedge a_j$ just to rule out the extra case $c'=a_j.$)  If $j\neq i$ then by an automorphism swapping $c'$ and $b_j$ but fixing $B\cup \{b_i\},$ we have $b_j\preceq b_i,$ contradicting minimality of $b_i.$
The remaining case is $c'<a_i.$ By the Lemma, $c'\leq b_i$ and $c'\leq a_i-b_i,$ which cannot happen for $c'>0.$

Comment: How is $\hat A$ related to $A$?

Comment: @Pteromys: no difference, that was my misunderstanding. I have corrected this now.